# Reference request for Minimal Surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

I need books or articles based on minimal surfaces. By minimal surface, I mean a surface with 0 mean curvature.

More specifically, I wish to explore the Plateau's Problem: There exists a minimal surface with a given boundary.

I would also like to see a proof of the fact that a surface of revolution that is minimal is either a plane, helicoid or a catenoid.

As a supplementary text, could I also have a reference for calculus of variations? (Unimportant, but why is calculus of variations not taught as a course in universities?)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may also try [this](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-121/).

Comment: Anyone please suggest some problem books on this topic "minimal surfaces"?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the books [Calculus of variations and the Plateau problem](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/4399.html) and [Variational methods](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9783540740124) by M. Struwe might be relevant to your question. Also, calculus of variations is teached in some universities, but usually only to advanced students. I happened to follow a course by professor Struwe on the material of the second book mentioned above during my MSc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall check out the books.

Comment: Anyone please suggest some problem books on this topic "minimal surfaces"?

Answer (score 1):

some nice texts are the following

- Geometric Measure Theory and Minimal Surfaces - Bombieri, E.
- Lectures on Geometric Measure Theory - Simon, L.
- Minimal Surfaces and Functions of Bounded Variation - Giusti, E.
- Sets of Finite Perimeter and Geometric Variational Problems - Maggi, F.
- Calculus of Variations and PDEs - Ambrosio, L. & Norman, D.
- Gamma Convergence for Beginners - Braides, A.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look at these books.

Comment: Anyone please suggest some problem books on this topic "minimal surfaces"?